# Is it possible to bound this sum?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Maybe this question is too simple, but I have been thinking about it for several days and I can't find the solution.

Is it possible to show that the there exists a universal constant such that the  sum
$$(N-k)\sum_{n=N-k}^{N-1}\frac{log(n)}{n^2}$$
is bounded for every $k,N\in \mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq k \leq N-1$?

I know that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{log(n)}{n^2}$ converges, so  I am trying to relate the previous question to the question of how fast this series converges but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

EDIT: Thanks to the answer given by @Conrad it is clear that it is not possible to bound the sum. But is it true for

$$(N-k)\sum_{n=N-k}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^2}\log\left(\frac{n(N-n)}{N}\right)?$$

Comment: I am trying to prove the existence of a universal constant. I just edited the post

Comment: For $k=N-1$ you'll get the constant $-\zeta'(2)\approx 0.937548254315843753702574$ as $N\to\infty$ but as indicated by Conrad your sum will grow without limit before going back to this value.

Answer (score 4):

The sum is actually unbounded as one can easily see for $k=N/2$ when $N=2M$ even. Then $$(N-k)\sum_{n=N-k}^{N-1}\frac{log(n)}{n^2}=M\sum_{n=M}^{2M-1}\frac{log(n)}{n^2} \ge \frac{1}{4M}\sum_{n=M}^{2M-1}\log n$$ since $1/n^2 > 1/(2M)^2, n \le 2M-1$. But:

$$\frac{1}{4M}\sum_{n=M}^{2M-1}\log n \ge \frac{\log M}{4}$$ since $\log n \ge \log M, n \ge M$ and there are $M$ terms in the sum.

It actually can be shown that that is the right behavior in the sense that $(N-k)\sum_{n=N-k}^{N-1}\frac{log(n)}{n^2}=O(\log N)$

Comment: After reading your answer I am wondering if the same is true for the series that I have write in the edit. I don't see now how to bound the function as you did with $log(n)\geq log(M)$

Comment: you can do same thing but now with $N=4M$ and the sum between $2M, 3M$ (so for $k=2M$) say so $\frac{n(N-n)}{N} \ge M/2$ and that part of the sum still has $M ~ \sim N$ terms (while the rest of the terms are nonnegative except maybe a few so do not really matter); in general for sums like this look at the terms were $k \sim N$ (and $N-k \sim N$ if you have $N-k$ around)  and those will generally tell you what happens